# Could not find gem 'uglifier' in the current bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bluehost

My simple web app runs ok on Windows 7. Now I am moving it to bluehost.

Getting this error when starting the app:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (cannot load such file -- uglifier
```

Trying to resolve it I have run 'gem install uglifier' and seems to mostly work:

```
SSH# gem install uglifier
Successfully installed uglifier-1.3.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for uglifier-1.3.0...
unable to convert "\xC2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII  for README.md, skipping
Installing RDoc documentation for uglifier-1.3.0...
unable to convert "\xC2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for README.md, skipping
```

But when I try to locate the gem, it is not found:

```
bundle show uglifier
```

yields:
    Could not find gem 'uglifier' in the current bundle

Gemfile includes the following:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

and Gemfile.lock shows that the uglifier gem is installed:

```
uglifier (1.3.0)
```

$PATH information:

```
/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home4/mychairs/perl5/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/home4/mychairs/perl5/bin:/ramdisk/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home4/mychairs/ruby/gems/bin:/home4/mychairs/ruby/gems:/home4/mychairs/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters you need to add the gem to your Gemfile at the root of your Rails application. See [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/).

Simply include the uglifier gem somewhere in the assets group of your Gemfile:

**Gemfile**

```
group :assets do
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

Then you run the `bundle install` command to install all of the required gems. You can confirm exactly what gems are installed including version information by looking at the Gemfile.lock file.

If you don't already have an assets group then make one. I highly recommend reading up on bundler.

Comment: My Gemfile and Gemfile.lock both seem to be in order (added by edit above).

Comment: Turning off javascript commpression has, for the time being, removed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try it with following in the app directory

```
#first
bundle
#then
bundle install
```

Comment: Same result - bundle runs fine but uglifier is not found. If it matters, 'uglifier' is not shown in the list of "Using xxx" gems that go by during the bundle execution.